# No such file or directory, not pointing to the right file - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bazaar

I have a weird problem.

I have a Rails (2.3) App where today after some commit/push action I found in a view directory some files like this:

```
/presentacion_en.html.erb
/presentacion_en.html.erb.~1~
```

I want to get rid of the .~1~ one, but if I delete it, i get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in StaticController#show

No such file or directory -
/var/www/app/views/static/presentacion_en.html.erb.~1~
```

Why is the app pointing to .~1~ when the html code looks like this:

```
<a href="../staticpages/presentacion_en" class="flag">Link</a>
```

If it helps, I'm using Bazaar as version control.

Comment: It looks like a backup file created by a text editor/IDE.  The href in a link needs to be a publically accessable path in your app, to load a file or to call a controller action.  It looks more like a partial, the way you're using it.  What is this link actually supposed to do?

Comment: The link destination is: /presentacion_en.html.erb when you click on it. Or it was till this .~1~ appeared...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself:

I don't know where this backup files came from, but I just removed them, and restart the server and all start working again!

Thanks Max Williams for the effort!